# what does nn.Linear() do in pytorch's last, and why is it necessary?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working with some code that trains an lstm to generate sequences. After training the model, the lstm() method is called:

```
x = some_input
lstm_output, (h_n, c_n) = lstm(x, hc) 
funcc = nn.Linear(in_features=lstm_num_hidden,
                  output_features=vocab_size,
                  bias=True)
func_output = func(lstm_output)
```

I've looked at the documentation for `nn.Linear()` but I still don't understand what this transformation is doing and why it is necessary. If the lstm has already been trained, then the output it gives should already have a pre-established dimensionality. This output (lstm_output) would be the generated sequence, or in my case an array of vectors. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's added _after_ the model has been trained? Can you provide the context, i.e. the training loop. It's very strange if the model has already been trained.

Answer (score 5):

Here, the Linear layer is transforming the hidden state representations (`lstm_output`) produced by the LSTM into a vector of size `vocab_size`. Your understanding is perhaps wrong. The [Linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=linear#torch.nn.Linear) layer should be trained along with the LSTM.

And I guess you are trying to generate a sequence of tokens (words), so the Linear layer should be followed by a [Softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html?highlight=softmax#torch.nn.functional.softmax) operation to predict a probability distribution over the vocabulary.

Comment: This makes sense,  given the lack of archetecture

Comment: `lstm_output` is the logit output. One has to apply a softmax operation on top of these logit scores to get a prob. distribution over the vocabulary.

Comment: kmario23 can you elaborate on "logic output"? I can't find any documentation on this that I can understand. In my case I have an lstm trained with pre-trained word2vec vectors. I'm trying to use the model as a sequence generator, and I want my output to be a word2vec vector in the vocabulary. `At first I thought I could set the dimensions of the output_features of nn.Linear to be same as the w2v embeddings, but the generated sequences end up being too long and I think this is due to the fully connected layer. Is  setting Linear's output features to the size of my w2v vectors a good approach?